# Why am I not able to switch-off my Windows Phone while it is charging?

Tags: lumia, charging

Today I bought a Nokia Lumia 525 and I tried to switch it off while charging but I was not able to do that since my phone automatically turned on after being switched off.

There is no problem in charging the mobile. But if I unplugged the charger I'm able to switch-off the mobile. Why its happening like this? Is there any problem with my mobile or is it a usual behavior only?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is standard behaviour for all Windows Phone 7 devices and Windows Phone 8 devices ([except HTC WP8 phones running GDR 3](http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-update-3-enables-powered-charging-htc-8x)).

Given that other systems don't always exhibit this kind of behaviour, there is a lot of user generated material about this:

- [Feature request to enable charging while the device appears to be powered off](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2845712-keep-phone-switched-off-phone-while-charging-no-)
- [General discussions confirming that everyone is experiencing this issue](http://forums.wpcentral.com/nokia-lumia-620/231245-phone-does-not-stay-off-while-charging.html)
- [And some explanations as to why it is the way it is](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wpdevices/the-windows-phone-7-will-turn-on-automatically/f6fd8b9c-e295-4814-b29e-14674f8b9944)

Given that OS updates are expected for WP8, this may change going forward.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behavior for a Lumia phone. When the phone is charging, it is turned on. If the phone was off, even because of low battery, plugging it in will turn the phone on.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, on WP 8.x and 7.x when you plug in the phone, it always switches on itself and you can't turn it off.

You'll be able to charge your phone *while* it is switched off when you'll upgrade to Windows 10 mobile, as stated [here](http://www.winbeta.org/news/windows-10-mobile-devices-can-now-be-charged-whilst-powered).