# my windows phone won't charge whlie on only while off

Tags: 8.1, battery, charging

So I plug it up and it charges until it turns on and then stops why is it not charging I've tried changing chargers and turning it of but it doesn't work

Comment: What phone do you have? What charger are you using? Wired or wireless? Do you have any resource-intensive apps running in the background?

Comment: See also: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3181/106

Comment: Have you tried replacing the battery?